# How to resize a UIButton in a UITableView footer when orientation changes

Tags: iphone, uitableview, footer, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm using two UIButtons in a footer of a UITableView (both subviews of a single UIView). I am not using a UITableViewCell because I wanted to skin the button so it looks like the red Delete button at the bottom of some iPhone screens such as when editing a contact.

It is sized and works correctly. However, the table will resize itself on device orientation changes (landscape, portrait and so on) and the button stays its original width. I tried using autoresizing masks but nothing worked.

Is there a trick to it, or a better way?

Comment: What do you return for `viewForFooterInSection:`? the button or a view with a button in it?

Comment: I return a view with a button in it (two buttons, actually).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should work with autoresizingmasks, I've done it before but it's important to set the width of your view correctly and add the correct sizingmasks.

Some sample code to show how it works. This creates two buttons resizing whem you rotate.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 50)];

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIButton *buttonA = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buttonA.frame = CGRectMake(20, 5, 125, 40);
    [buttonA setTitle:@"ButtonA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonA.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    [view addSubview:buttonA];

    UIButton *buttonB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buttonB.frame = CGRectMake(175, 5, 125, 40);
    [buttonB setTitle:@"ButtonB" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonB.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    [view addSubview:buttonB];

    return [view autorelease];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code I noticed what my problem was...I hadn't set the frame of the buttons' superview...that's why my autoresizing masks weren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Please use 2 frames for button one for landscape mode and another for portrait mode..this will work out..so when orientatin changes check whetehr its landscape or portrait and assign frame for it...check mode here
willrotatetointerfaceorientation

Comment: Thanks. But there should be a way for the table to take care of it I would think.

Answer (score 0):

Best i've come up with is, use one button and one cell in its own section, then each will resize appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar to yours except I only have one button.  the uiview that you are returning should be the same width as the tableView itself.

```
CGFloat footerWidth = mainTableView.frame.size.width;
CGRect frameTableFooter = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, footerWidth, 60.0);  
viewForTableFooter.frame = frameTableFooter;
// buttons addition
mainTableView.tableFooterView = viewForTableFooter;
```